# "not all arguments converted during string formatting" taking modulus where isnumeric() is True

Tags: python

```
while True:
    ans = input('Enter a number : ')
    if ans.isalpha():
        if ans == 'q':
            break
    elif ans.isnumeric():
        if ans == 1 or ans == 0:
            print('NOT even NOR odd number')
        elif ans % 2 == 0:
            print('EVEN number')
        else:
            print('ODD number')
```

and goes error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Me.Qa/Desktop/app0001.py", line 9, in <module>
    elif ans % 2 == 0:
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're taking the modulus of a string?

Comment: Put `ans = int(ans)` after `elif ans.isnumeric():`.

Comment: I think you intended to parse the string as a number before doing math on it or comparing it against numbers. Use `int`.

Comment: PS: since when is `1` not and odd number?

Comment: ...and since when is 0 not an even number?

Comment: I've tried to edit the title to be more specific and descriptive. Please try to make a title that's specific to the individual question being asked (so others know if a question's answers are likely to help them without needing to click through first) in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You din't convert "ans" variable to int. Just add

```
ans = int(ans)
```

before

```
if ans == 1 or ans == 0:
```

Comment: Tanks dude, helpfull

Answer (score 0):

`ans` is a String. You can't do math on a String; you need to parse it as a number first.

As noted in the comments, change you second part to:

```
elif ans.isnumeric():
    # int takes a string and returns 
    #  the number it represents
    num_ans = int(ans) 
    if num_ans == 1 or num_ans == 0:
        print('NOT even NOR odd number')
    elif num_ans % 2 == 0:
        print('EVEN number')
    else:
        print('ODD number')
```

Comment: Tanks dude, helpfull

Comment: You can do a few types of math on a string, you just can't do numeric math with it.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams What math can you do on a string? I don't know if string multiplication counts as math.

Comment: Concatenation, replication, and interpolation are all done via mathematical operators.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Maybe because they use math operators to carry them out, but I don't think they really count as "math". I think you're splitting hairs here.